# Count rows based on condition within specified timeframe

Tags: r, datetime, count, vectorization

I have 2 dataframes in R out of which data has to be merged. Dataframe **snap** contains a site column, 2 datetime columns each 15mins apart that represent a 15min time window.
The snap df looks like this

```
SITE      SNAPSHOT_DATE1      SNAPSHOT_DATE2 AS_PREALLOC_ACTIVE 
1   US 2022-10-01 00:00:00 2022-10-01 00:15:00                                                  
2   US 2022-10-01 00:15:00 2022-10-01 00:30:00                                                  
3   US 2022-10-01 00:30:00 2022-10-01 00:45:00                                                  
4   US 2022-10-01 00:45:00 2022-10-01 01:00:00                                                  
5   US 2022-10-01 01:00:00 2022-10-01 01:15:00                                                  
6   US 2022-10-01 01:15:00 2022-10-01 01:30:00
```

The dataframe **custexperience** contains the data that needs to be fed into the **snap** df.

```
   AS_SITE     AS_ORDER_CREATE  AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM
1       US                <NA> 2022-10-03 14:42:31
2       US                <NA>                <NA>
3       US                <NA> 2022-10-02 10:42:01
4       US                <NA>                <NA>
5       US                <NA>                <NA>
6       US                <NA>                <NA>
7       US                <NA>                <NA>
8       US                <NA> 2022-10-02 10:42:01
9       US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:17
10      US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:18
11      US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:18
12      US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:17
13      US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:17
14      US 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 17:38:47
15      SG 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:18
16      SG 2022-10-03 14:19:16 2022-10-03 14:41:18
```

What I want to accomplish is the following, I already have it working in a for loop (but this can be quite slow): for all entries in custexperience df that match the following criteria, the total count of matching rows needs to be written into the snap df.
Example: all the rows in custexperience where AS_ORDER_CREATE is between snap$SNAPSHOT_DATE1 and snap$SNAPSHOT_DATE2 or where AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM is between snap$SNAPSHOT_DATE1 and snap$SNAPSHOT_DATE2 or where AS_ORDER_CREATE is < SNAPHSHOT_DATE1 and AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM is > SNAPSHOT_DATE2.

```
-i=0
for(i in 1:nrow(snap)) {
  # prealloc
  prealloc = custexperience[custexperience$AS_SITE == snap[i, "SITE"] & 
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_ORDER_CREATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE1"] & 
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_ORDER_CREATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE2"] | 
                              custexperience$AS_SITE == snap[i, "SITE"] &
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE1"] & 
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE2"] |
                              custexperience$AS_SITE == snap[i, "SITE"] & 
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_ORDER_CREATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE1"] & 
                              as.POSIXct(custexperience$AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE2"], ]
  prealloc <- prealloc[!is.na(prealloc$AS_ORDER_CREATE),]    
  snap[i, "AS_PREALLOC_ACTIVE"] <- nrow(prealloc)
```

Since this is only 1 example (I have some more conditions for more columns in snap that need to be filled), my question is: how can I achieve this with vectorized commands?

Expected output is the following:

```
  SITE      SNAPSHOT_DATE1      SNAPSHOT_DATE2 AS_PREALLOC_ACTIVE 
1   US 2022-10-01 00:00:00 2022-10-01 00:15:00 7                                                  
2   US 2022-10-01 00:15:00 2022-10-01 00:30:00 5                                                 
3   US 2022-10-01 00:30:00 2022-10-01 00:45:00 1                                                 
4   US 2022-10-01 00:45:00 2022-10-01 01:00:00 0                                                 
5   US 2022-10-01 01:00:00 2022-10-01 01:15:00 0                                                 
6   US 2022-10-01 01:15:00 2022-10-01 01:30:00 11
```

**#**

dput(head(snap))

```
> dput(head(snap))
structure(list(SITE = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US"), 
    SNAPSHOT_DATE1 = structure(c(1664575200, 1664576100, 1664577000, 
    1664577900, 1664578800, 1664579700), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SNAPSHOT_DATE2 = structure(c(1664576100, 
    1664577000, 1664577900, 1664578800, 1664579700, 1664580600
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), AS_PREALLOC_ACTIVE = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), AS_ALLOC_ACTIVE = c("", "", "", "", 
    "", ""), AS_PICK_ACTIVE = c("", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(head(custexperience))

```
structure(list(DELIVERY = c(617850869L, 617850875L, 617850875L, 
617850875L, 617850875L, 617850875L), SALES_DOCUMENT = c("T03341390", 
"T03340586", "T03340586", "T03340586", "T03340586", "T03340586"
), MATERIAL = c("TL431AIDR", "MAX3237EIPW", "MSP430FR5739IRHAR", 
"MSP430FR5962IZVWR", "TMS320C6747DZKB3", "TMS5700232BPZQQ1"), 
    AS_SITE = c("SZ", "SZ", "SZ", "SZ", "SZ", "SZ"), SHIPPING_POINT = c(1285L, 
    1285L, 1285L, 1285L, 1285L, 1285L), ITEM_DELIVERY = c(10L, 
    160L, 80L, 140L, 120L, 150L), SALES_DOC_ITEM = c(10L, 160L, 
    80L, 140L, 120L, 150L), AS_ORDER_CREATE = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), AS_ORDER_COMPLETE = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), AS_PREALLOC_CT_HR = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), AS_ALLOC_CT_HR = c("0", "", "0", "", "", 
    ""), AS_PICK_CT_HR = c("0.483888888888889", "", "0.123888888888889", 
    "", "", ""), AS_ORDER_CT_HR = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    AS_PREALLOC_AVG_OTHERS = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AS_ALLOC_AVG_OTHERS = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AS_PICK_AVG_OTHER = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), AS_FRST_ALLOC_DTTM = structure(c(1664800951, NA, 
    1664700121, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    AS_LST_ALLOC_DTTM = structure(c(1664800951, NA, 1664700121, 
    NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    AS_FRST_PICK_DTTM = structure(c(1664802676, NA, 1664700555, 
    NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    AS_LAST_MOVE_DTTM = structure(c(1664802693, NA, 1664700567, 
    NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide your dataframes using `dput()` instead of `print()`?

Comment: @jrcalabrese The dfs are fairly large (snap 3.5k lines and custexperience 25k lines) so I just posted a head() of those here. I just added a dput(head(snap)) and dput(head(custexperience))

Comment: For info, I have noticed that `snap$SNAPSHOT_DATE1[i]` is much faster than `snap[i, "SNAPSHOT_DATE1"]`

Comment: You may try an [inequality join with dplyr](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/)

Comment: Try to apply the `as.POSIXct` function on each column before the loop

Comment: Why do you repeat the condition `custexperience$AS_SITE == snap[i, "SITE"]`?

Comment: You may look at the `outer` function